# infinit scroll issue in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape information from a site https://www.kw.com/agent/search/ca. I can move to desired elements by using Actionchains.The problem is scrolling further deep down.The script stucks after completing first 50 elements . how should I modify my script to load further elements.
It would be very helpful if someone gives me a workaround. Thanks

```
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains, Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import re


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.kw.com/agent/search/ca/")
driver.maximize_window()
# Locate the element with the accept name
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#__next > div.app.app--consumer > div.KWBanner.KWBanner--cookieAcceptance > div > button")))
# Click the element
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#__next > div.app.app--consumer > div.KWBanner.KWBanner--cookieAcceptance > div > button")).click().perform()

html_content = '<div class="row FindAgentRoute__totalCount"><div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-l-4 col-xl-4">Showing 1,188 Agents</div></div>'

# Use regular expression to extract the number
match = re.search(r'Showing ([0-9,]+) Agents', html_content)
result = 0
if match:
    # Get the matched number and remove commas, then convert to int
    number_str = match.group(1).replace(',', '')
    result = int(number_str)
    print(result)
else:
    print("Number not found in the string.")
def scroll_page():
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).perform()


def getdata(response):
    htm = response
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htm, 'lxml')
    json_data = json.loads(soup.find('script', {'id': '__NEXT_DATA__'}).get_text())
    name = json_data['props']['pageProps']['agentData']['name']['full']
    city = json_data['props']['pageProps']['agentData']['location']['city']
    state = json_data['props']['pageProps']['agentData']['location']['state']
    email = json_data['props']['pageProps']['agentData']['email']
    website = json_data['props']['pageProps']['agentData']['website']
    print(f"{name}, {city}, {state}, {email}, {website}")
    pd.DataFrame([[name, city, state, email, website]], columns=['Name', 'City', 'State', 'Email', 'Website']).to_csv('kw.csv', mode='a', header=False)

#wait until acceptance of cookie button with id "onetrust-accept-btn-handler" is clicked
#element = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "KWButton KWButton--primary KWButton--red")))
#ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "KWButton KWButton--primary KWButton--red")).click().perform()
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "AgentCard")))
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "AgentCard")
print(len(elements))

try:
    for counter in range(40, result + 1):
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
            xpath = f'//*[@id="kw-skip-nav"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[{counter}]/div'
            print(xpath)
            elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))

            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)).click().perform()
            print(driver.current_url)
            WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "AgentContent__section")))

            getdata(requests.get(driver.current_url).text)

            driver.back()
            if counter % 50 == 0:

                scroll_page()
                time.sleep(4)

        except:
            print("no luck")



except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("broken link")

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any scroll should be finite :)

In your case, there is a label which shows how many agents are there. You can utilize that number to figure out how many records you want to collect.

You can use the following approach:

- Get the target number of iterations
- start collecting records from starting row - 0 (first agent) to the current max number of displayed rows
- after collecting the last one, use ActionChains to move to that last element (maybe add some additional 10px scroll if it is needed), this will trigger the loading of the next 'portion' of agents
- change the starting row number - to the number of the row you've moved to
- start the next loop iteration from the n-th row to the current max number of displayed rows (it should be the previous number + a portion of newly loaded ones)

You can also add some iterations control mechanism, to not end up with the infinite loop (it may be caused by some UI changes/lags)

I don't know your exact business case (I see you are using bs4 also), but the following code works ok for me (1190 names were collected):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

try:
    driver.get("https://www.kw.com/agent/search/ca")

    # get total count of agents
    total_count = 0
    total_count_label = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "FindAgentRoute__totalCount")]'))).text
    match = re.search(r'\b(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*|\d+)\b', total_count_label)
    if match:
        total_count = int(match.group().replace(',', ''))

    iteration = 0
    tail_agent_id = 0
    collected_agents = []
    while len(collected_agents) != total_count:
        if iteration > total_count / 2:
            raise RuntimeError("Too many iterations")

        for i in range(tail_agent_id, len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="AgentCard"]'))):
            el = wait.until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'(//div[@class="AgentCard"])[{i + 1}]'))
            )

            # your parsing logic goes here
            # your parsing logic goes here
            # your parsing logic goes here

            name = el.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[contains(@class, "AgentCard__name")]').text

            collected_agents.append(name)
            print("Collected: " + name)

        tail_agent_id = len(collected_agents)
        actions.move_to_element(
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'(//div[@class="AgentCard"])[{tail_agent_id}]')
        ).perform()

        iteration += 1
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

You can adjust it for your needs, i.e. leave only moving to the last element action, and do the parsing with bs4.

Comment: Yes This script does the scrolling right but scaping names is not the goal but email and other things as well. I have made script that visits the page and clicks on each agent profile to get data. Then back. So when I am doing the driver.back() command after each profile visit it takes me back to the first page. Next page is never loaded in that case.

Comment: @GyanDixit, oh man, It will take an eternity if you're going to open each agent one by one. I just double-checked your website, in theory, you can do the same w/o Selenium, just with requests. You can open the dev tools (F12 in Chrome), switch to the network tab and refresh the page. You will see a POST request to the 'https://api-endpoint-cons-system.cons-prod-us-central1.kw.com/graphql' endpoint (simple POST with json).  In JSON body you can change 'first:50' to 'first:9999' (or grab the actual number from the UI, if you still want to use the selenium). Will continue in another comment.

Comment: @GyanDixit, but you have to add 'X-Shared-Secret' header to your request. You can obtain it by sending a GET request to the 'https://www.kw.com/agent/search/ca' endpoint. In the HTML response, you can find a 'graphQLAPISecret' key (it is basically in the script tag, but you can extract it with python). So with the header attached you will receive a JSON response, under data/SearchAgentQuery/result/agents/edges you will find an array of agents, each agent has node/id key. If you click on any agent, with the network tracing opened, you will see another POST request, to the exact same endpoint

Comment: @GyanDixit, but with a different body. In body, the only thing you need to change is variables/id value (ids were collected from the previous request's response). Don't forget to attach the 'X-Shared-Secret' header (same as for the previous POST). So, in the response of the 2nd POST you will get a JSON with all the data you need. Just loop over all the collected IDs, and collect the data you need. Let me know it you need some help with requests.

Comment: I studied graphql a bit and manually made one jason file from about 20 graphql files that were visible during scroll. I then extracted id's and using request I extracted data from the site . It worked well and I found what I needed . Surprisingly the website has changed now with a differrent layout. It needs login as well now.